# RoutingContext.vertx() is null in Vertx's BodyHandler (Nullpointerexception during file upload)

Tags: file-upload, nullpointerexception, vert.x

My vertx instance worked fine as long as it answered to standard json requests. Once I tried the file upload (that already worked in other vertx projects), I got a NPE in Vertx's BodyHandlerImpl. There `context.vertx()` returns null:

```
    SEVERE: Unexpected exception in route
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl$BHandler.<init>(BodyHandlerImpl.java:124)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl.handle(BodyHandlerImpl.java:65)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl.handle(BodyHandlerImpl.java:40)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteImpl.handleContext(RouteImpl.java:217)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:78)
...
```

You can clone a **minimal example to reproduce** the error here: https://github.com/cburnicki/vertx-file-upload-test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Vert.x Web `Router` cannot be a final member of the verticle class:

```
public class MainApiVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
  final Router router = Router.router(vertx); // vertx field is not set yet
  // ...
}
```

When it is created, the verticle is not deployed so the `vertx` field from the parent class is still `null`.

If you need it as a field, initialize it in the `start` method:

```
public class MainApiVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    Router router;

    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
        router = Router.router(vertx);
        // ...
    }
}
```